# If value of cell equals X, get value of adjacent cell, then add to totals

Tags: google-sheets

I have a budgeting spreadsheet, with separate spending categories, and I want to SUM all spending entries based on the category selected. I'm not technical, but here's an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
check each cell in column C and column F
if cell = category 1 
get adjacent value from column B or column E
add value to relevant category total
```

I've created an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12c8ezGdYTb0n6D5hF3f28JtrXBeOMU_mY22uQ-dDMZY/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to previous contributions, this should also work:

```
=sumproduct({$C$3:$C$9; $F$3:$F$9}=A12, {$B$3:$B$9; $E$3:$E$9})
```

and drag down.

The first literal array {} makes one column out of the C-range and the F-range. The second one does the same with the B-range and the E-range. When the 'first column' equals the contents of cell A12, the 'second' column (or the adjacent cell) is summed.

Comment: Interesting! I don't understand how the `{$C$3:$C$9; $F$3:$F$9}=A12` part works. Does this evaluate to an array of `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal: you are correct. The array-enabler here is of course sumproduct(). Otherwise you would have to wrap that part in ArrayFormula().. =ArrayFormula({$C$3:$C$9; $F$3:$F$9}=A12) to output that array of TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @JPV - is it possible to modify this formula to calculate the totals if the labels are different? i.e. if Label = "1", and Total Label = "Category 1", Label = "2", Total Label = "Category 2" etc, I have updated the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12c8ezGdYTb0n6D5hF3f28JtrXBeOMU_mY22uQ-dDMZY/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, sure. If you have less than 10 labels/categories, you can use the right() function: =sumproduct({$C$3:$C$9; $F$3:$F$9}=right(A12), {$B$3:$B$9; $E$3:$E$9}). If you need more than 10 labels, you may consider the use of regextract: =sumproduct({$C$3:$C$9; $F$3:$F$9}=REGEXEXTRACT(A12, "\d+"), {$B$3:$B$9; $E$3:$E$9})

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with the `SUMIF` function ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)).

In cell `B12`, enter:

```
=SUMIF(C$3:C$9, A12, B$3:B$9) + SUMIF(F$3:F$9, A12, E$3:E$9)
```

`SUMIF` takes 3 arguments; the first being a range to be matched against a search value (second argument), and the third being the values to be summed.

So `SUMIF(C3:C9, A12, B3:B9)` looks at the `C3:C9`, for each cell that matches the contents of `A12`, the corresponding value from the `B3:B9` range is added to the sum.

The `SUMIF` construct is repeated again, to include the values for Week 2.

---

The `FILTER` function *could* work here, **but will fail with an error** if there are no values for a given category.

For example, in your `B12` cell (sum for *Category 1*), enter

```
=SUM(FILTER(B$3:B$9, C$3:C$9 = A12)) + SUM(FILTER(E$3:E$9, F$3:F$9 = A12))
```

Explained:
The `FILTER`  function takes two parameters, the first being the *source* range, the second being a *condition*. For each value in the *source* range, the *condition* is tried. Only if the *condition* is true, is the source value included in the result. The condition in this case, is that the `C` and `F` columns should be equal to `A12`, which is `Cat 1`.
The `SUM` function then acts on the values returned from the `FILTER` function.

This construction is repeated twice, once for the *Week 1* columns, and once for the *Week 2* columns.

---

Once you have pasted the formula into cell `B12`, you can drag the mouse across the other category sum cells, and the formula will be copied there.

I have copied your example spreadsheet, and modified it according to this answer. You can see [my copy here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s2inflKwlxbgWYMt2XjlxXnH-HpxUrbKOFqGbLZ37So/edit?usp=sharing).

Also see the [documentation for the `FILTER` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197).

Comment: Thanks Vidar. This is almost the ideal solution for me, the only adjustment I would like to make, is to show the full name / label for the Category Total, e.g. "Category 3", instead of "Cat 3". Is there any way to adjust the `FILTER` function to accommodate a different name / label?

Comment: This would be easy, as `Cat 3` is not hardcoded anywhere in the formula - the value is taken from the corresponding cell in column `A`. So when `A12` is `Category 1`, values from Week 1 and Week 2 that are labelled `Category 1` will be included. However, trying to demonstrate this, I found a flaw in my formula, leading me to use `SUMIF` instead. I have updated the answer and the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the new solution. I still have a question though - is it possible to calculate the totals if the labels are different, i.e. Label = "1", Total Label = "Category 1", Label = "2", Total Label = "Category 2" etc, I have updated the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12c8ezGdYTb0n6D5hF3f28JtrXBeOMU_mY22uQ-dDMZY/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate.

Comment: Not with the current formula, no.

Answer (score 2):

This solution isn't exactly what you asked for, but certainly a lot easier to maintain.

If you position the data vertically (see screenshot *data*), then the following formula will suffice and still work when adding more weeks without having to make adjustments.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(
   B3:C, 
   "SELECT C, SUM(B) 
    GROUP BY C 
    OFFSET 1 
    LABEL C 'Categories', SUM(B) 'Sum'
   "
 )

copy / paste 
=QUERY(B3:C, "SELECT C, SUM(B) GROUP BY C OFFSET 1 LABEL C 'Categories', SUM(B) 'Sum'")
```

### Explained

First the data range is set: the complete column range of B and C, starting at row 3. Then column C is selected and the sum of column B. All is grouped by the categories (column C). The *offset* parameter in the formula is used (in this case) to skip an empty row (because it will try to sum all blank rows as well). The *label* parameter makes it possible to create different headings.

### Screenshot

*data*
[image]

*result*
[image]

### Note

When you decide to add more items or to add a category (arbitrarily throughout the weeks), the `QUERY` formula takes all into account. Initially you will get an error, because the result overwrites the summation in `F9`. All you have to do is to remove the summation in `F9` and the result will expand automatically. Do remember to add the summation again...

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Conditional Sum](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBmUwb2xVUSc8qZ1HfVZW5rP3DJWOd14MkVhV0cI3bo/edit?usp=sharing)**